# How to load multiple views without using storyboard in xcode 6.2

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

I created an iOS 8 project in XCode 6.2, I removed the storyboard, modified the appDelegate and the plist file. I added a new view (named "primary", with the xib, h, and m files) with a button and called it from the modified appdelegate. It works so far. I created a second view (named "second") and want to call it from "primary" once the button is called.

I tried adding the code below from Primary's button click event:

```
    second *secondView = [[second alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:secondView animated:NO completion:nil];
```

*Result: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Would be nice if anybody can help me or point me on how to load a view from another view programatically without using Storyboards?

Thanks in advance.

Best Regards,
VinceV

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a `UINavigationController`? please show us some more of your project since im not able to solve this question with the current info provided

#### Edit

Make sure you call the `presentViewController` code from your second
ViewController

```
//Button Event in SecondViewController.m
(void)handleClick:(id)sender
{
    SecondViewController * controller = [SecondViewController] alloc] init];
    
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:true completion:nil];

}
```

Comment: Hi, tried exaclty that code and still getting "*Result: Attempt to present on whose view is not in the window hierarchy!"

Comment: Hi Jason, yehey it did work on the button click event, sorry i was putting it on Primary's viewDidLoad initially. Is it possible also to do this on the viewDidLoad, like a login screen?